# What are all the animation duration constants in UIKit?

Tags: ios, animation, ios7, uikit

What are all the public animation duration **constants** (or readonly properties) defined in UIKit as of iOS 7?

E.g.:

In *UINavigationController.h*:

```
UIKIT_EXTERN const CGFloat UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration;
```

In *UIApplication.h*:

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSTimeInterval statusBarOrientationAnimationDuration;
```

(to clarify, I'm not asking about their values)

Comment: NSLog doesn't help you?

Comment: I did a quick search using: `grep --include="*.h" -EHrn "[[:alnum:]]+Duration" /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk`. I'm sure there are more scattered around.

Comment: @AndrewShmig How would it help?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I didn't ask about the values.

Comment: Lots of properties/methods if you search "animationduration" through the private header files: https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=animationduration&type=Code

Comment: Found another one: `CATransaction.animationDuration() // 0.25`